# Export-Csv throws error when handling dates

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to search Active Directory and get a report of usernames and when their certificates expire.  Here is the code I've cobbled together from other sources. When I run it manually in a PowerShell window, it's showing me the `NotAfter` date that I want.

[image]

But when I try to write to a CSV file it's telling me the `NotAfter` value is a "System.Object[]".  One site mentioned using JSON format but this isn't very friendly to the eyes.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
$cert = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $StrFilter -server $domain -searchbase $searchOU -Properties "Certificates"
Foreach ($i in $cert)
{
    $tempobj = $cert.Certificates | foreach { New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_ }

    If ($Cert.Certificates.Handle -eq $null)
    {
        $Rep = "" | Select "Account", "NotAfter"
        $Rep."Account" = $cert.name
        $Rep."NotAfter" = "N/A"
        $Myobj += $Rep
        $Rep = $null
    }
    Else
    {
        $Rep = "" | Select "Account", "NotAfter"
        $Rep."Account" = $cert.name
        $Rep."notAfter" = $tempobj.NotAfter
    }

    $Myobj += $Rep
    $Rep = $null
}

#After the loop, export the array to CSV
$Myobj | sort | export-csv -Path C:\xtemp\scripts\pshell\UserCerts.csv -notype
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  Why are you using `foreach ($i in $cert)` and then *never using `$i`*?  Instead you specifying `$tempobj = $cert.Certificates | [...]`.  Shouldn't that be `$tempobj = $i.Certificates | [...]`?

Comment: Apologize for the sloppy code.  I've been searching the internet for ways to do this and this was the result of some mixing.  I had something like that coded originally but still got the same result when pushing it to a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some major updates in your code...
This Should be a starting point:

```
$cert = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $StrFilter -server $domain -searchbase $searchOU -Properties "Certificates"
$cert = $cert | ? {$_.Certificates}
$Myobj = @()

Foreach ($i in $cert)
    {
    $tempobj = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $i.Certificates

    $Rep = "" | Select Account, NotAfter

    If ($i.Certificates.Handle -eq $null)
        {
        $Rep.Account = $i.name
        $Rep.NotAfter = "N/A"
        }
    Else
        {
        $Rep.Account = $i.name
        $Rep.NotAfter = $tempobj.NotAfter.ToString()
        }

    $Myobj += $Rep
    }
```

Comment: This worked.  I thought I had tried "ToString()" before...I think my sloppy code got in the way.